# modify web.config programmatically c# vs2010

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-config

I am able to modify database conection and mailsetting web.config from web setup project; however can't figure out how to modify a custom section:

```
<configuration>
<projectConfig siteName="name" supportEmail="" adminEmail="" thumbnailSize="120" />
</configuration>
```

I get these values from a cutom action in my setup project.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270287/editing-web-config-programatically

Comment: I can't help but think you are looking for the xml transforms. (google this xdt:Transform="SetAttributes") This gets set as per your environment on deploy. If that's not what you are wanting to do that config is easily (and more appropriately) stored in a database.

Comment: I am trying to change the web.config from a custom aciton using c# for example:  appDatabase1.Name = "MainDBContext";
            appDatabase1.ConnectionString = applicationConnectionString; I can find the coonnectionstring section, but have no idea how to find a configuration section that I have added to web.config mannually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:
http://foreachbiscuit.wordpress.com/2007/10/11/custom-webconfig-settings/