# Changing Linq To SQL Connection String after Compile vb .net

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net, linq, connection-string

I'm developing an application by VB.NET which includes an installation wizard. It uses LINQ to SQL.

Is there any way that in last page of installation wizard I can set the connection string once, and the application can then use it after installation?

Comment: put it in the app.config file.

Comment: Tnx , But How? consider i have a textbox on my form and in want to save connection string through that textbox.

Comment: You can programmatically edit the app.config file when the user clicks Enter/Next after typing in the connection string.

Comment: yes, but i cant find any namespace that lead me to app.config file.
do i need to edit it like an XML file?

Comment: @Farhad yes, it's just an xml file that you would write to.

Comment: See if this question helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270287/editing-web-config-programatically