# Programmatically change the page redirection in web config

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi i want to change the Page redirection in webconfig programmatically.
i have following code in web config.

```
<location path="WebForm2.aspx">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://google.com" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
```

i want to enable or disable the httpredirect programmatically using c#.
please suggest me how to do this.

Comment: have you checked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270287/editing-web-config-programatically

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the code suggested by Rahul but I wasn't able to change the `<location>` element of the `Web.config` programatically.

As an alternative you could write an HttpHandler to intercept the request to the `WebForm2.aspx` page and redirect the user to another URL:

**Handler:**

```
namespace StackOverflowHelp
{
    public class RedirectHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            Uri uri = context.Request.Url;

            if (uri.AbsolutePath == "/WebForm2.aspx.aspx")
                context.Response.Redirect("http://google.com");
        }
    }
}
```

**Handler registration in the Web.config:**

```
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add verb="*" path="WebForm2.aspx"
       name="RedirectHandler"
       type="StackOverflowHelp.RedirectHandler"/>
    </handlers>
```

Comment: Sir i want to change the path in <location path="*"> in webconfig at runtime or change the httpRedirect enabling or disabling at runtime. i dont want to redirect the page from code behind i want it from webconfig only. i dont put any redirection code in the page source. For changing the webcofig i use another page not the same page whose i redirect to.